# SquishIt Framework causing KeyNotFoundException on the server

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, bundling-and-minification

I am using the SquishIt Framework for minification and it is working fine on the local end but when I push it on the server I get KeyNotFoundException. Below is the stack trace for the error.

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: KeyNotFoundException 
Exception message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
at SquishIt.Framework.Base.BundleBase`1.GetCachedBundleState(String name)
at SquishIt.Framework.Base.BundleBase`1.RenderCachedAssetTag(String name)
at ASP.seasiawebsitemasterpage_master.__RenderHead1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I have been trying very hard but I am unable to re generate the error on the development machine.

I any other information is required then please leave a comment.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/issues/222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the issue was caused due to the IIS pipeline mode being set to Classic. Changed the mode to integrated and the problem was resolved.